# Solve : $(2x - 4y + 5) \frac{dy}{dx} + x - 2y + 3 = 0 , y(2) = 2.5$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to find the solution of following differential equation:

$$(2x - 4y +  5) \frac{dy}{dx} + x - 2y + 3 = 0 , y(2) = 2.5$$

It can be re-written as

$$(2(x - 2y) +  5) \frac{dy}{dx} + (x - 2y) + 3 = 0$$

let $u = (x-2y)$

so, on differentiating both sides with respect to $x$ we get

$$\frac{du}{dx} =  1 - 2\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}$$

$$\therefore \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1 - \frac{du}{dx}}{2}$$

using this value in initial equation we get,

$$(2u + 5) (\frac{1-\frac{du}{dx}}{2}) + u + 3 = 0$$

On further solving we get

$$\frac{2u + 5}{4u + 11}.\frac{du}{dx} = 1$$

Integrating both sides with respect to $x$, we get

$$\int \frac{2u + 5}{4u + 11}.du = \int dx$$

$$\implies \int (\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{8u + 22})\cdot du = x + C$$

$$\implies \frac{1}{2}\cdot u - \frac{1}{8} \ln(8u + 22) = x + C$$

putting the value of $u$ in the above equation we get,

$$\implies \frac{1}{2} (x-2y) - \frac{1}{8} ln(8(x - 2y)+ 22) = 2 + C$$

we have, when $x = 2 , y = 2.5.$

When I put these value of $x$ and $y$ in  the above equation to obtain the value of $C$

$ln(-negative Value)$ is obtained, what is wrong here?

The answer given in the book is :

$$4x + 8y + ln(4x - 8y + 11) = 28$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a mistake in following step and it is rectified in next step

$ \frac{1}{2}\cdot u - \frac{1}{8} \ln(8u + 22) = x + C$

$\implies  \frac{1}{2}\cdot u - \frac{1}{8} \ln(|8u + 22|) = x + C$

$\implies  \frac{1}{2}\cdot (x-2y) - \frac{1}{8} \ln(|8x-16y + 22|) = x + C$

When $x=2$ $y=2.5$, therefore

$\implies  \frac{1}{2}\cdot (2-5) - \frac{1}{8} \ln(|8*2-16*2.5 + 22|) = 2 + C$

$\implies  \frac{1}{2}\cdot (-3) - \frac{1}{8} \ln(|16-16*2.5 + 22|) = 2 + C$

$\implies   - \frac{1}{8} \ln(2) = 3.5 + C$

$\implies   - \frac{1}{8} \ln(2)-3.5=  C$

Therefore our solution becomes

$\implies  \frac{1}{2}\cdot (x-2y) - \frac{1}{8} \ln(|8x-16y + 22|) = x  - \frac{1}{8} \ln(2)-3.5$

$\implies  4x-8y -  \ln(|8x-16y + 22|) = 8x  -  \ln(2)-28$

$\implies 4x+8y + \ln(|8x-16y + 22|)-\ln2=28$

$\implies  4x+8y + {\ln(|4x-8y + 11|)}=28$

Comment: Should I use modulus inside $ln$ i.e $\int \frac{1}{x}\cdot dx= ln\mid{x}\mid $?

Comment: @AbhilekhGautam yes https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-ab/ab-integration-new/ab-6-8b/v/antiderivative-of-x-1#:~:text=Integration%20goes%20the%20other%20way,is%20ln(%7Cx%7C).

Comment: $ln  \mid x \mid $ makes sense now

Answer (score 3):

The answer was given by Lalit Tolani. This is an additional information.

From the implicit equation
$$4x+8y+\ln(4x-8y+11)=28$$
the explicit solution $y(x)$ cannot be expressed with a finite number of elementary functions. It can be analytically expressed on closed form thanks to a special function namely the Lambert's W function.

Let $X=8y-4x-11\quad\implies y=\frac18(X+4x+11)$
$$4x+(X+4x+11)+\ln(X)=28$$
$$X+\ln(X)=-8x+17$$
$$Xe^X=e^{-8x+17}$$
From the definition of the Lambert's W function :
$$X=W(e^{-8x+17})$$
$$8y-4x-11=W(e^{-8x+17})$$
$$\boxed{y(x)=\frac{4x+11+W(e^{-8x+17})}{8}}$$